# NHibernate and newly created records locking

Tags: nhibernate, locking

I have two tables. 
Wallet turnovers and Wallet Balances.

Wallet turnovers are credit and debit operations over wallet in specific currency and for specific client.

Wallet balances contains for each client and currency at most one record, which contains balance for client and currency. Balance is a result of a sum of credits and debits from wallet turnovers.
I want to application behave the way, that when I add turnover to turnovers table, I need to recalculate balance table by addition of amount of current turnover. If record for currency and client of current turnover doesnt exists yet, I would like to create a new one.

Problem is, how should I prevent application to create multiple records of balances for same client and currency in balances table.

Imagine case, that I'm adding turnover for client with id=1 and currency=USD.
The record doesnt exists yet so it should be created.
But what happens when two concurent users A and B of application at same time add turnover for client 1 and currency USD?

What should I pls do to achieve behaviour, that when I create for first time wallet balance record by user A and it had not been saved to database now, second user B of application would have to wait till first user commits its records, only than read the current balance(which contains updated balance from user A) and continue with correct value of balance?

Can something like this be even achieved? How should I let nhibernate know, that record of balance with client id = 1 and currency = USD has already some user created and so, when other user looks for this combination in table, this record is already created and user should wait till user A commits it?

Code of GetOrCreateBalance:

```
    public ClientWalletBalance GetOrCreateWalletBalance(int clientId, int currency)
    {
        var clientObj = ClientService.GetClient(clientId);

        var res = clientObj.WalletBalances.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Currency.Id == currency);

        if (res == null)
        {
            res = new ClientWalletBalance()
            {
                Client = clientObj,
                Currency = ClientService.GetCurrency(currency),
            };
        };
        clientObj.WalletBalances.Add(res);

        return res;
    }
```

I already know, that this can be achieved by

session.Lock(object, LockMode.Upgrade);

I just dont clearly understand, if I lock newly created object, which is not saved to DB yet - so it doesnt have id associated, how would nhibernate know that combination of client 1 and currency USD was already created is some other users "memory?"

What is the standard recipe for cases like this please?

Thank You very much,

Peter

EDIT 1:
Till yet, I ended up with something like this:
Calling code:

```
using (ISession session = NHibernateConfiguration.ReturnOpenedSession())
            {
                using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    var cwb = Service.OrderAndPaymentService.GetOrCreateWalletBalance(clientId, currency, delay);

                    response.Error = cwb.Balance.ToString();

                    transaction.Commit();
                }
            }
```

`

Called code:`

```
public ClientWalletBalance GetOrCreateWalletBalance(int clientId, int currency, int delay = 0)
        {
            var clientObj = ClientService.GetClient(clientId);

            var res = clientObj.WalletBalances.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Currency.Id == currency);

            if (res != null)
            {
                NHibernateConfiguration.GetCurrentSession().Lock(res, LockMode.Upgrade);
            }
            else
            {
                res = new ClientWalletBalance()
                {
                    Client = clientObj,
                    Currency = ClientService.GetCurrency(currency),
                    Balance = delay,
                };

                clientObj.WalletBalances.Add(SaveClientWalletBalance(res));

                NHibernateConfiguration.GetCurrentSession().Lock(res, LockMode.Upgrade);
            }

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay * 1000);

            return res;
        }
```

`

But there is still problem with possibility that two different web users will call the same combination of client Id and currency for the first time, in that case two records for same client and currency will be created. And I cant use lock(object) syntax, because we use web farm which has multiple aplication servers that dont share static variables.

Comment: I found how is balance/turnover pattern handled with lock statement. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement So perhaps I could use lock statement too. What concerns me is this line from nhibernate documentation : NHibernate will always use the locking mechanism of the database, never lock objects in memory! Is this statement true also in case I'm creating new WalletBalance record in memory?

Comment: I ended up with something like this:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want objects to be unique over some properties in the database, you should ensure this by defining the proper UNIQUE constraints in the database. It will then ensure there won't be duplicates.

In next step you want to think about what should happen if two processes does try to add duplicate records because they are running concurrently:

- You can either trap the UNIQUE violation and have that process retry. On second
  go it will find the record committed by the other transaction.
- You can use SERIALIZABLE transaction isolation level. This is the safest isolation
  level. If I'm thinking correctly, it should ensure that when any process tries to
  read an existing record it will either get no record, the existing record, OR if
  any other open transaction have already looked for the same record it will block
  and wait until the other transaction has finished.